# SISS MSSQL to MySQL with different collation is not copying finnish letter å

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis, odbc, collation

I don't think title could be more described better as tl;dr, because problem is a bit deeper.

I've got two databases (finnish language):

**MSSQL (collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_CI_AI)**

**MySQL (collation: utf_general_ci)**

I've created BI project in vs2017, connected two databases and transfered tables from one to another, no problem. Except for 1 letter: "å" - instead it was "?". I cannot change any database collation so I am trying to find a way to transfer words with this letter.

What I've tried:

1. OLD DB Source -> ODBC Destination
2. Point "1" with "Data Conversion" block in between (with code page 1252)
3. Script Component, in which I have tried:

   - Insert with "_latin"

     ```
     sql= "INSERT INTO db.words(Name) VALUES(_latin1'å')";
     byte[] b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sql);
     odbcCmd = new OdbcCommand(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b), odbcConn);
     odbcCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     ```
   - Insert without it

     ```
       sql= "INSERT INTO db.words(Name) VALUES('å')";
       byte[] b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sql);
       odbcCmd = new OdbcCommand(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b), odbcConn);
       odbcCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     ```
   - Diferent ways of encoding

     ```
      byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes("å");
      var myString = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(bytes);
      byte[] bytes2 = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("å");
      var myString2 = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes2);
     ```
   - Insert with COLLATE which got me error

     ```
      insert into db.words(Name) values ("å" COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci) ;
     ```

and error:

> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: „ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver][mysqld-5.7.21-log]COLLATION 'latin1_swedish_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'cp1250'”

Here is interesting part:

**I can make insert with this letter in MySQL Workbench without a problem**, and it will be inserted, but when I try to pass it from one database to another it is lost. I've set Data Viewers between Data Conversion and the letter was still there, and also when debugging script it was after encoding in string that were inserted to database.

Maybe someone got any idea what else I can try, because I feel like I have tried everything, and feel that the resolve of this problem is really close, but I just don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

- CP1250 does not include `å`; CP437 and utf8 do include it.
- `COLLATE` is irrelevant -- it applies only to comparing and sorting.
- Don't use any encode/conversion functions; instead, *specify* how the data is encoded.
- I see 'code' -- but what is the encoding for the source in that language and/or editor?
- Show us the hex of any strings in question.
- Which direction are you trying to transfer?
- What are the connection parameters for each database?